# Why is this last used getElementsByTagName ("a") [0]?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Document</title>
     <script>
      window.onload=function()
      {
       var oTab = document.getElementById('tab1');
       var oName = document.getElementById('name');
       var oAge = document.getElementById('age');
       var oBtn = document.getElementById('btn');
       var id =  oTab.rows.length+1;
       oBtn.onclick=function()
       {
        var oTr = document.createElement('tr');
        var oTd = document.createElement('td');
        oTd.innerHTML = id++;
        oTr.appendChild(oTd);
    
        var oTd = document.createElement('td');
        oTd.innerHTML =oName.value;
        oTr.appendChild(oTd);
    
    
        var oTd = document.createElement('td');
        oTd.innerHTML = oAge.value ;
        oTr.appendChild(oTd);
    
    
        var oTd = document.createElement('td');
        oTd.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:'>删除</a>" ;
        oTr.appendChild(oTd);
    
        oTd.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick=function()
        {
         oTab.tBodies[0].removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        }
        
    
        oTab.tBodies[0].appendChild(oTr);
    
    
       }
      }
      
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     姓名：<input id="name" type="text" />
     班级：<input id="age" type="text" />
     <input id="btn" type="button" value='添加' />
     <table id="tab1" border="1px" width="600px">
      <tHead>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>操作</td>
      </tHead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I do not understand, createElement created a label to add delete function, why oTd.getElementsByTagName ('a') [0] .onclick = function () which is selected TagName [0], not every time to create a Tag to trigger js. Why not do a loop for each a to add onclick

Comment: because there is just one `a` element in that element. Personally I would just create the a element and not use innerHTML to it and there would be no look up.

Comment: So after the creation of a number of a, then need to use for loops to add onclick?

Comment: There is no loop for adding onclick... not sure what your comment means. There is one new anchor in the cell so the code selects the anchor and adds an onclick to it. Since the method returns an HTML collection and not just one element, the code needs to use bracket notation to get the first index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Purpose

The purpose of the code is to add a click handler to every `<a>` element that gets created. When `<a>` is clicked, it removes the row which is the part in the body of the `function`.

```
                var oTd = document.createElement('td');
                oTd.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:'>Delete</a>" ;
                oTr.appendChild(oTd);

                oTd.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick=function()
                {
                    oTab.tBodies[0].removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
                }
```

You could replace the `innerHTML` with a more explicit `createElement`.

```
                var oTd = document.createElement('td');
                var anchor = document.createElement('a');
                anchor.textContent = "Delete";

                oTd.appendChild(anchor);
                oTr.appendChild(oTd);

                anchor.onclick = function() {
                    oTab.tBodies[0].removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
                }
```

### Breakdown

We can change the following one line into multiple lines and explain each step.

#### Before

```
oTd.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick=function() { alert('Clicked!') };
```

#### After

```
// Get all child <a> elements 
var anchorElements = oTd.getElementsByTagName('a');

// Get the first <a> element
var a = anchorElements[0];

// Attach a click event handler to the element
a.onclick = function() { alert('Clicked!') };
```

Comment: Would you like to ask that the top comments can not be accepted? Do not use ^ _ ^